# test time-based scripts

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime

I'm writing a simple script which has a few lines like this:

```
if (datetime.datetime.hour == 12):
```

What is the easiest way to test these? Changing the system time to different times every time I want to test it is a bit annoying, is there an easier way to let Python think it's a different time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a datetime object `now` and use it:

```
import datetime, pytz

testing = False # set to True/False

if testing:
    now = datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 12, 23, 34, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    # testing with any time
else:
    now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    # normal usage with current time

if (now.hour == 12):
    ...
```

**EDIT:** You can also start your script with an optional parameter (check [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)): if it is filled in a YYYYMMDDHHMMSS form, you can parse it:

```
if optDate: 
    now = datetime.datetime.strptime(optDate, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
else:
    now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

Apply your own timezone here if you want.

Comment: brilliant! One more thing: how would I let the script ask me what time I want it to be when I run it? (Only when testing = true obv.)

Comment: @JacobK: the script shouldn't have to ask you anything.  Write your unit tests to set `now` to different values that should have different results.

Comment: Sorry, bit unclear. What I meant was that instead of defining now in the script, I'd like to let the script ask for it as soon as I run it. I gave it a try with dt = datetime.datetime(raw_input), but that didn't work.

Comment: @JacobK - don't ask for it - enter it through a command-line parameter (see my edit)